# Create custom map with annotations in Swift

Tags: swift, annotations, uiimage, mapkit

Is there a way with Swift to realise something similar like this http://www.dayzdb.com/map Can I load an UIImage, that I can pinch and zoom and place annotation or images on specific locations. Or is there a way with the MapKit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maps are made up of *tiles* and alot of them, not a single image. See this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158175/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-tiles) for more information and a tutorial

Comment: @Scriptable so I could seperate the Image in multiple tiles and use it that way?

Comment: Yes, read the article though. you need to create alot of tiles all of different sizes for different zoom levels. it is not an easy task.

Comment: @Scriptable Ahh ok.. And there is no easy way with the uiimageview?... But still thanks for your answer, I will give it a try at home

Comment: you could create a fake map with a high res image of a map and a scrollview yeah, but it will have limitations